# How to resolve ANR for MapsInitializer.initialize?

Tags: android, google-maps

The MapsInitializer.initialize method forces you to be called on main thread, and yet it causes ANRs.

ANR:

```
ii: Application Not Responding for at least 5000 ms.
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:511)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:644)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:1447)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.o.A(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200031.477283333.477283333:41)
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.ay.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200031.477283333.477283333:8)
    at fjj.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200031.477283333.477283333:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200031.477283333.477283333:35)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.logInitialization(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200031.477283333.477283333:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.bo(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200031.477283333.477283333:5)
    at baw.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200031.477283333.477283333:4)
    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
    at js8.A(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:8)
    at h49.N0(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:13)
    at q84.a(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:99)
```

Running on non main thread:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread
                                at xy.j(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200065.477283333.477283333:0)
                                at xy.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200065.477283333.477283333:1)
                                at com.google.android.libraries.geo.crash.monitoring.UncleanTerminationDetector.i(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200065.477283333.477283333:6)
                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200065.477283333.477283333:53)
                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.logInitialization(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200065.477283333.477283333:1)
                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.bm(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200065.477283333.477283333:5)
                                at ayk.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_maps_core_dynamite@223812200@223812200065.477283333.477283333:4)
                                at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1164)
                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zze.zzl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:4)
                                at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:12)
```

Comment: Just saw a spike in scrashlytics about this one too, I have no idea what to do

Comment: I've moved it to application onCreate (which turns out does not cause ANRs even blocking longer than 5s) however it increases app start substantially which is not great considering when you don't even need to use google maps on first screen. :/